# Is there a way to override the js function present in a jsp using a function in a js file that is included in the jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a function

```
function clearform() {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; (i < document.forms.length); i++) {
        document.forms[i].reset();
        }
```

in the abc.jsp(say) and i have a js file included in the jsp name xyz.js(say)
is there a way to override the function clearform by adding something in xyz.js as making changes on the jsp is out of scope now because of the deployment process etc.

The function is called using the below call in the body tag

```
 <body onUnload="javascript:clearform();">
```

Comment: just some ideas without testing. maybe add another onbeforeunload event listener in the js file and do the updated thing there? or maybe you can construct a script DOM node in the js file and append it to the end of the jsp body...

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your html content before  put like this

```
<script>
(function(){
   window.clearform = function() { }
})();
</script>
</body>
```

Which will override that function